# Bulk Insert support for Unicode seperator

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am using Azure data factory to Archive data from Azure Sql Db to Azure Blob Store and Bulk insert to retrieve the data.

I am using below as row and column seperator.

Column delimiter:\u0001

Row delimiter:\u0003

My Bulk Insert is below.

```
BULK INSERT mytable 'MyPath/file.txt'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MySource',FIELDTERMINATOR ='\u0001', ROWTERMINATOR   = '\u0003');
```

I am getting the below error:

Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

Documentation said Unicode is supported for  FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR   then what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unicode is not fully supported for bulk insert.

> **Only the t, n, r, 0 and '\0' characters work with the backslash escape character to produce a control character.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=azuresqldb-current